# Pattern Recognition Problem: If $7,24 \to 25 ; 12,35 \to 37;$ ... , then M=?

Tags: pattern

A friend has given me a puzzle to solve, the puzzle is as follows:
$$\color{red}{7 \, , } 24 \to \color{blue}{25}$$
$$\color{red}{12 \, , } 35 \to \color{blue}{37}$$
$$\color{red}{11 \, , } 60 \to \color{blue}{61}$$
$$\color{red}{8 \, , } 15 \to \color{blue}{17}$$
$$\color{red}{9 \, , } 40 \to \color{blue}{\text{M}}$$
then $\color{blue}{\text{M}}$=?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> 41 because $red^2 + black^2 = blue^2$.

These are all

> Examples of Pythagorean triples, and so $9^2 + 40^2 = 81 + 1600 = 1681$, and then $\sqrt{1681} = 41 = M$.

Answer (score 8):

Although El-Guest answer appears correct for all the listed cases, there could be a simpler answer, which is:

> if red is uneven then black + 1
>  else if red is even then black + 2

Comment: Huh. I do think that @El-Guest is correct, but this is very interesting.

Comment: There are plenty of example cases that would satisfy the intended solution but not this one (e.g., $\color{red}{28 \, , } 45 \to \color{blue}{53}$), and there are plenty of example cases that would satisfy this solution but not the intended one (e.g., $\color{red}{4 \, , } 5 \to \color{blue}{7}$). It's a shame that no case like either of these was in the puzzle to make the solution unambiguous.

Comment: See also [this picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PrimitivePythagoreanTriplesRev08.svg) (warning: spoiler for the intended solution). The overlap between the two solutions happens to be everything along the left and bottom edges in it.